# Why is t-SQL order by datetime correct in SQL SMS but not in ASP Classic output?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bootstrap-4, datatables, asp-classic

When querying the below select in T-SQL the output is ordered as it should, but when I use the select in Classic ASP, the order is not ordering correct:

```
SELECT ChangeDate, ID, DataString, Operation, Area, ChangedBy
FROM EFP_LOG
WHERE Operation = 'Created'
ORDER BY ChangeDate DESC;
```

The output in SQL Server Management Studio is:

```
2021-06-06 21:13:17.177
2021-05-31 15:46:38.603
2021-05-31 15:43:21.967
2021-05-31 15:42:02.987
2021-05-31 15:41:44.493
...
```

Output in Classic ASP is (output format is correct displayed : DD-MM-YYYY hh.mm.ss):

```
05-05-2021 21:33:54
05-05-2021 21:41:52
05-05-2021 21:43:46
05-05-2021 21:45:35
06-06-2021 21:13:17
07-04-2021 07:39:03
...
```

Tabel Layout:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| PRIMARY KEY | COLUMN NAME   | DATA TYPE     | ALLOW NULL | DEFAULT VALUE |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   YES       | ID            | int           | NO         | Identity (1,1)|
|             | DataString    | VARCHAR(8000) | YES        |               |
|             | Operation     | VARCHAR(255)  | YES        |               |
|             | Area          | VARCHAR(255)  | YES        |               |
|             | ChangedBy     | VARCHAR(255)  | YES        |               |
|             | ChangeDate    | datetime      | NO         | GetDate()     |
|             | ADdisplayName | VARCHAR(255)  | YES        |               |
|             | ADMail        | VARCHAR(255)  | YES        |               |
|             | ADCompany     | VARCHAR(255)  | YES        |               |
|             | ADdepartment  | VARCHAR(255)  | YES        |               |
|             | ADtitle       | VARCHAR(255)  | YES        |               |
```

I have tried several approaches using FORMAT, CAST and CONVERT, but none of them is working, what could be the issue?

**Update with ASP code:**

```
<%

    Set UserCreationLogConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    UserCreationLogConn.ConnectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB; DATA SOURCE=<SERVER>;UID=SA;PWD=<PASSWORD>;DATABASE=<DATABASE>"
    UserCreationLogConn.Open

    UserCreationLogSQL = "SELECT ChangeDate, ID, DataString, Operation, Area, ChangedBy, ADmail, ADcompany, ADdepartment, ADtitle FROM EFP_LOG WHERE Operation = 'Created' ORDER BY ChangeDate DESC;"

    Set objUserCreationLog = UserCreationLogConn.Execute(UserCreationLogSQL)

    While Not objUserCreationLog.EOF

      Response.Write objUserCreationLog("ChangeDate")

    objUserCreationLog.MoveNext

    Wend
    objUserCreationLog.Close
    Set objUserCreationLog = Nothing
 %>
```

**Output of SQL CREATE To from SMS:**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EFP_LOG](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DataString] [varchar](8000) NULL,
    [Operation] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Area] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [ChangedBy] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [ChangeDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ADdisplayName] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [ADmail] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [ADcompany] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [ADdepartment] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [ADtitle] [varchar](255) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_EFP_LOG] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EFP_LOG] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__EFP_LOG__ChangeD__4A0FA628]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [ChangeDate]
GO
```

Comment: You need to show the code you use to execute the SQL the likelihood is you're missing the `ORDER BY`. The fact you’ve tried using `FORMAT`, `CAST` etc tells me you’re approaching the problem wrong. You want to sort by the raw `datetime` and output the formatted date as a string. You don’t want to order using the formatted string as that will not be treated like a date and you’ll get unexpected results.

Comment: If `ChangeDate` is a strongly typed `datetime` value, then the SQL you've provided won't return the data in that order, meaning that either the column *isn't* a strongly typed `datetime`, that isn't the SQL  your *really* using (in your application), or your performing more sorting in your application.. What ever it is, we need more information.

Comment: @user692942 I have updated post with ASP

Comment: Sorry but as already said there is no way that `ChangeDate` is a `datetime` data type in SQL, it’s clear that `ORDER BY` is treating it like a string and you mentioned `CAST` and `CONVERT` before? Is `EFP_LOG` a table or view?

Comment: I am sorry to correct you @user692942, the ChangeDate IS a datetime data type as you can se in the SQL Create To script I have just added. .. I have tried Cast, Format and Convert barely to get a reaction other than the one I get from the real code, I am aware that I cannot order by formated string, and I am not trying to do so.

Comment: @StigKølbæk In which case if that is all the SQL and you are querying using the raw table schema then I can't see any logical reason for that to be happening. Maybe the ADO SQL provider you are using is causing the problem, SQLOLEDB is quite old now?

Comment: @StigKølbæk You've tagged the question [tag:datatables] have you tested this without the AJAX element involved, just raw response loop from ADODB?

Comment: @user692942 you got a point .. I have just found out that DataTables is automatically adding type to a column as `text` if it is not able to detect the type itself, which is the case here since the output is localized as Danish, and therefor cannot figure out that it is a datetime .. I will add the solution to this thread in a moment. Feel free to post an answer, then I will accept it since you lead me to the solution.

Comment: It's always best to if you think SQL Server is the problem is test it in a raw a format as you can, if it works in SSMS but not in Classic ASP is the Classic ASP doing a simple `Response.Write()` loop and nothing else? That's the initial reason you got the feedback you did. If you hadn't tagged the question with [tag:datatables] we'd be none the wiser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was that using DataTables, the query, and returned datetime column was treated as a text string since it could not figure out my localization.

The solution, after checking this page https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type was to add the below columnDefs to the datatable

```
$('#dtBasicExample').dataTable( {
  "language": {
      "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Danish.json"
  },
  "columnDefs": [
    { "type": "date", "targets": 0 }
  ]
 
} );
```